# Deserialization c# object and passing values in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I need to ask you guys about after deserialization, the process is okay but I need to know how could I print these values to the screen?

Here is my example code it is working on Windows Phone 8 environment.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;
using JsonSample.Resources;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace JsonSample
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
           var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
          // tbl_result.Text = rootObject;
          // Console.WriteLine(rootObject);
          // Use The rootObject
        }

        //This event of button placed in grid
        private void btn_Parse_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //WebClient for pinging my api
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            webClient.DownloadStringCompleted += webClient_DownloadStringCompleted;
            webClient.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://echo.jsontest.com/id/4456482/type/ggfd"));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is MainPage XAML

```xaml
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="JsonSample.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
    FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
    Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
    SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
    shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="JSON PARSING" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="lets parse" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
            <Button x:Name="btn_Parse"  Click="btn_Parse_Click" Content="Show me parsed data!" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="77,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="306"/>
            <TextBlock x:Name="tbl_result" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="39,100,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="376" Width="378" FontSize="24" Foreground="#FFFFF300"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage>
```

RootObject.cs here:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace JsonSample
{
    public class RootObject
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to deserialize to xaml?". can you show us your xaml code?

Comment: thank you i updated, i just want to see a returning value on the phone screen, at this time there is nothing printing how can i do that? thanks

Comment: tbl_result.Text = rootObject dosen't display the deserialized json? did you debug and check what the deserialization is returning from the web request?

Comment: no, Error 1 Cannot implicitly convert type 'JsonSample.RootObject' to 'string' C:\Users\DC\Desktop\C#\JsonSample\MainPage.xaml.cs 27 29 JsonSample

Comment: how can i do that? how can i see the output, i am stuck at that point

Comment: Show me your RootObject class implementation

Comment: try this tbl_result.Text = rootObject.ToString(); what is rootObject actually show its class as well.

Comment: i have updated, tbl_result.Text = rootObject.ToString();  returns  the name "JsonSample.RootObject" on the screen...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this :

```
void webClient_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result) as RootObject;
    tbl_result.Text = rootObject.type;
}
```

Comment: how can i bind this result to like to a long list selector?list.ItemsSource = new rootObject(); not applicable,

Comment: @user3529738 You should bind some List to list.ItemsSource , for example: list.ItemsSource = rootObject.ToList();

Comment: it returns with error i have added this to current XAML http://pastebin.com/CSqDEEtn

Comment: Read this link it might help you : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207023(v=vs.105).aspx